# Sustituir decimales y agregar .00 a un numero entero

Tags: php

quisiera ayuda en esto.
Tengo un numero por ejemplo este 250.50 y quisiera cambiarlo a este numero 250.00, o sea sustituir las decimales por .00 y tambien que al poner un numero entero por ejemplo este 250 se agreguen los .00. Esto es una pagina que al ingresar los datos se subiria a una base de datos

Comment: para la primera parte de la pregunta busca como redondear hacia abajo en php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php

```
<?php
echo number_format(300, 2, '.', '');
?>
```

esto da como resultado 300.00